# why does my jquery.ajax() function show 'Aborted' when uploaded to a live server

Tags: jquery, ajax, firebug, abort

Why does my `jQuery.ajax()` function work perfectly on my local server, but when uploaded I now get an 'aborted' response in Firebug?

[image]

The ajax function is calling the same domain, and looks like this

```
jQuery.ajax({
  url: homeUrl+'/engine/check/',
  data: jQuery('#post').serialize(),
  type: 'post',
  beforeSend:function(){
    jQuery('#checker span').text('checking status...').parent().show();
  },
  success: function(data){
    if(data == 'not_gallery'){
      jQuery('#checker').hide();
    }

    if(data == 'no_folder'){
      jQuery('#loader').hide();
      jQuery('#checker span').html('please ensure you have chosen a folder to connect to this gallery');
    }

    if(data == 'complete'){
      jQuery('#loader').hide();
      jQuery('#checker span').html('Gallery Active');
    }

    if(data == 'in_crunch'){
      jQuery('#loader').show();
      jQuery('#checker span').html('Crunching in progress. This may take a while...');
      refreshIntervalId = setInterval( 'check_poll()', 15000 );
    }

    if(data == 'init_crunch'){
      jQuery('#loader').show();
      jQuery('#checker span').html('Crunching in progress. This may take a while...');
      jQuery.post(homeUrl+'/engine/crunch/', jQuery('#post').serialize(), function(data){
        if(data == 'done'){
          jQuery('#loader').hide();
          jQuery('#checker span').html('Gallery Active');
        }                                                                                     
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Could it be my nested ajax functions?

Comment: Without further details, it's hard to tell you why.

Comment: First guess would be a cross-site scripting issue.

Comment: I've got no further details - the response is blank and the return status just says 'Aborted'

Comment: @Ash How could expect us to solve your problem, if you don't provide any details? What is the URL you use? Is it on the same domain? How do you call the function?

Comment: @Ash Could you tell us from Firebug what is the same exact URL it is trying to call? What is `homeUrl`?

Comment: You can get aborted if you try to reload the page or navigate away.  Anything like that going on?

Comment: One thing I encountered is if the action attribute of the form does not match the url in the ajax call, the call is aborted.

Answer (score 0):

On such instance where i faced this problem was due to apache web server configuration.

The server was configured to accept x mb of data and my payload was more than x.

Check the access log if this is happening.

In this case for me, firebug was showing "aborted" and chrome developer tool was showing "pending" on the POST request.